# my app crash in IMGSGX543GLDriver

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

my app crash in IMGSGX543GLDriver ,the most difficult is there are not any code of my app in the crash log and i cannot reproduce it .This issue cost me several days and I still have no idea. Any ideas you guys provide, I will try. Thank you for your help.

```
Thread 12 name:  Dispatch queue: CA::CG::Queue
Thread 12 Crashed:
0   IMGSGX543GLDriver               0x31cb4ff0 glrRetainVendCtxPipeProg + 0
1   IMGSGX543GLDriver               0x31caf8d8 gpusLoadCurrentPipelinePrograms + 1664
2   IMGSGX543GLDriver               0x31cb948c gldUpdateDispatch + 396
3   GLEngine                        0x34184a0a gleDoDrawDispatchCoreES2 + 562
4   GLEngine                        0x3412ef72 glDrawElements_IMM_ES2Exec + 190
5   QuartzCore                      0x331bffc4 CA::OGL::GLContext::draw_elements(CA::OGL::PrimitiveMode, unsigned int, unsigned short const*, CA::OGL::Vertex const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, CA::OGL::ClipPlane const*) + 272
6   QuartzCore                      0x331bfe7c CA::OGL::Context::array_flush() + 48
7   QuartzCore                      0x331ef8ae CA::OGL::emit_combine_(CA::OGL::Context&, CA::OGL::TextureFunction, CA::OGL::Surface*, int, CA::OGL::Surface*, int, CA::OGL::Surface*, int, CA::Shape const*, CA::Vec4<float> const&) + 1114
8   QuartzCore                      0x331ef444 CA::OGL::emit_combine(CA::OGL::Context&, CA::OGL::TextureFunction, CA::OGL::Surface*, int, CA::OGL::Surface*, int, CA::OGL::Surface*, int, CA::Shape const*, CA::Vec4<float> const&) + 112
9   QuartzCore                      0x331e3560 CA::CG::DrawOp::render(CA::CG::Renderer&) const + 1940
10  QuartzCore                      0x331e1854 CA::CG::Queue::render_callback(void*) + 116
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x346e4d08 _dispatch_queue_drain + 268
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x346e4b6e _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 34
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x346e57e0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 204
14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32f67df4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32f67cc8 start_wqthread + 0
```

Comment: Have you checked the state of the other threads on the crash? Maybe there is some other similarities between the crashes.

Comment: i have several crash reports, the other threads may different, but the carsh thead is the same  like this.

Comment: Is this by any chance related to old devices (iphone4, ipad2) that have recently upgraded to iOS7 opening a web view?

Comment: I have this happening with an ipad 2 recently upgraded to ios 7 and an open webview...curious as to why?

Comment: Were you able to find a fix/workaround for this one?

Comment: @user1043479 I have an app that crashes with this on multiple devices a few times per week.  Still no idea as to why.  This app is running on an ipad 2 that opens a webview on ios 7.

Comment: @BenjaminOman I've got nothing provable, but it seems to be a memory issue.  I don't know if trimming memory usage in the rest of the app will help